# Is there any way to limit count of Sign In user flow in AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

**Edit**

It is not a duplicate: The other question is about **Sign Up**, this is about **Sign In**. What's more: That question is about email *verification*, this question about *quotas/throttling*. Those are different elements of a middleware policy. Although the consequences could be similar, the issue itself and *also the solution is different*. Please remove the duplicate flag

---

In case of a malicious user scripts her/his Sign In/Sign Out against your application/web site, which uses AD B2C it can cause millions of Sign In within a reasonable short term.

Because of you will be billed based on the count of Sign Ins (free for < 50 000, then pay) this will not be a happy hour.

**Question**

Is there any way to prevent the scenario above? (limiting payment is not an option, this case after the attack your site will be unable to serve Sign In user flow)

Comment: Not sure but will enforcing Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) help in your scenario - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome Azure AD B2C Sign Up accepts temporary email and sends verification code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56088351/how-to-overcome-azure-ad-b2c-sign-up-accepts-temporary-email-and-sends-verificat)

Comment: @SamCogan: No it's different: That question is about Sign Up, this is about Sign In. What's more: That question is about email verification, this question about quotas/throttling. Those are different elements of a middleware policy. Although the consequences could be similar, the issue itself and also the solution is different. Please remove the duplicate flag

Comment: @GauravMantri: yes, it definitely helps, but introduces a user experience what may or may not appropriate depending on the profile of the application/website

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C has mitigation techniques against malicious attacks like you the ones you described, and B2C will automatically lock out the user for a certain period of time.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-threat-management#password-attacks

At the moment, with smart lockouts(as mentioned in the link above) admins cannot control the number of attempts. But if you want to be able to configure that and maybe, even take an action (like MFA) you can do that with custom policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom

Azure AD B2C community on GitHub has a sample to lock out the user after 6 unsuccessful sign-ins. 
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/lockout

Comment: The question is not about password attack, instead signin/ signout sequences which are successful and cost the b2c owner money

Comment: You get charged only when B2C mints an id or access token, which happens 'only' after a successful sign-in. If I understood your question correctly, you are concerned that due to malicious attacks your tenant will be charged. I agree there is no way in B2C you can put an upper limit on the price you will be charged (it is a consumption-based model) but B2C has provisions where you can block sign-ins using smart lockouts or custom policies, which by won't mint access/id tokens. Hence, you won't be charged.

Comment: I am talking about successful logins